# The term for a kitchen device

Tags: meaning, nouns, translation

I want to translate a Russian fairy tale. There is a "device" I need an equivalent for. In Russian it is called "ухват" (uhvat), and it is used to put pots on the coals/into the oven. Is there anything alike in English? (The Google's "grip" doesn't fit).

Comment: We need a full description please before we have any hope of naming it. A picture would be excellent.  Does it clip onto the pot or pan? Is it cast iron or wood? Is it long for leverage like a handle?

Comment: On an open fire it might be a *gridiron* or *potstand* or *grating*.  In an oven, *oven shelf*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](https://context.reverso.net/translation/russian-english/%D1%83%D1%85%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82), it translates to an "oven fork". I did an image search for "ухват" and then for "oven fork" and some of the same images appeared in both as you can see [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=%D1%83%D1%85%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82&client=ubuntu&channel=fs&sxsrf=ACYBGNTLrXStkmUJUMwl2C4IegOfNSreNw:1579090915605&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiy2t6IzIXnAhXoURUIHcryDy4Q_AUoAXoECAsQAw&biw=1680&bih=856) and [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=oven%20fork&client=ubuntu&hs=ga5&channel=fs&sxsrf=ACYBGNQjCOF61IiXlI1Mo15cPiW4CHYc8g:1579090749579&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjpksm5y4XnAhWEsnEKHQwTDJ8Q_AUoAXoECAwQAw&biw=1680&bih=856), respectively.

For the benefit of the people asking for a photo in the comments, here it is:

[image]

Comment: I imagine for most readers “oven hook” would be more intelligible even if “oven fork” is historically idiomatic